# How to do if-else in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, jstl, thymeleaf

What's the best way to do a simple `if`-`else` in Thymeleaf?

I want to achieve in Thymeleaf the same effect as

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${potentially_complex_expression}">
     <h2>Hello!</h2>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     <span class="xxx">Something else</span>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

in JSTL.

What I've figured so far:

```html
<div th:with="condition=${potentially_complex_expression}" th:remove="tag">
    <h2 th:if="${condition}">Hello!</h2>
    <span th:unless="${condition}" class="xxx">Something else</span>
</div>
```

I don't want to evaluate `potentially_complex_expression` twice. That's why I introduced local variable `condition`. Still I don't like using both `th:if="${condition}` and `th:unless="${condition}"`.

An important thing is that I use two different HTML tags: let's say `h2` and `span`.

Can you suggest a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Thymeleaf has an equivalent to `<c:choose>` and `<c:when>`: the `th:switch` and `th:case` attributes introduced in Thymeleaf 2.0.

They work as you'd expect, using `*` for the default case:

```xml
<div th:switch="${user.role}"> 
  <p th:case="'admin'">User is an administrator</p>
  <p th:case="#{roles.manager}">User is a manager</p>
  <p th:case="*">User is some other thing</p> 
</div>
```

See [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew20.html#swit) for a quick explanation of syntax (or the Thymeleaf tutorials).

*Disclaimer*: As required by StackOverflow rules, I'm the author of Thymeleaf.

Comment: ok but..how do i invoke a javascript based on the type of customer(i.e anonymous or logged in)...

Comment: See the chapter on "Text inlining", specifically the "JavaScript inlining" section at the "Using Thymeleaf" tutorial in http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html

Comment: And how can I do th:switch on an iterator.index value? I want to do a set of cases when the value is <5, and switch to default case if value is >5

Comment: @DanielFernández: can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499723/thymeleaf-list-within-list-input . I couldn't tag you on the question directly. Really stuck.

Comment: The original question was asking about a boolean condition. How would you do that with `switch`? Would you make the first case be `th:case="true"`?

Answer (score 136):

I tried this code to find out if a customer is logged in or anonymous. I did using the `th:if` and `th:unless` conditional expressions. Pretty simple way to do it.

```html
<!-- IF CUSTOMER IS ANONYMOUS -->
<div th:if="${customer.anonymous}">
   <div>Welcome, Guest</div>
</div>
<!-- ELSE -->
<div th:unless="${customer.anonymous}">
   <div th:text=" 'Hi,' + ${customer.name}">Hi, User</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question because that was about avoiding duplicating complex expressions. And like other solutions, this breaks the "natural templates" idea, which is a major selling-point of Thymeleaf. Not sure what to do about it myself, but just wanted to point it out in case someone has an answer.

Comment: @Lucky this gives me an error  EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'Status' cannot be found

Comment: @Jackie In the above example customer is an object and anonymous is a boolean field in the Customer class. Make sure your object is not null and field name is correct.

Answer (score 34):

I'd like to share my example related to security in addition to Daniel Fernández.

```html
<div th:switch="${#authentication}? ${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')} : ${false}">
    <span th:case="${false}">User is not logged in</span>
    <span th:case="${true}">Logged in user</span>
    <span th:case="*">Should never happen, but who knows...</span>
</div>
```

Here is complex expression with mixed 'authentication' and 'authorization' utility objects  which produces 'true/false' result for thymeleaf template code.

The 'authentication' and 'authorization' utility objects came from [thymeleaf extras springsecurity3 library](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3).
When 'authentication' object is not available OR authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') evaluates to 'false', expression returns ${false}, otherwise ${true}.

Comment: That's a good tip, but note that you can use `true` and `false` literals—you don't need to use variable substitution expressions for them. See also [Yatendra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61764312/421049).

Answer (score 23):

You can use

```
If-then-else:  (if) ? (then) : (else)
```

Example:

```
'User is of type ' + (${user.isAdmin()} ? 'Administrator' : (${user.type} ?: 'Unknown'))
```

It could be useful for the new people asking the same question.

Answer (score 16):

Another solution - you can use local variable:

```html
<div th:with="expr_result = ${potentially_complex_expression}">
    <div th:if="${expr_result}">
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
    </div>
    <div th:unless="${expr_result}">
        <span class="xxx">Something else</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

More about local variables:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables

Comment: I think you have added an extra "=" sign in your code. Please verify it again and correct it if I'm right.

Comment: In my opinion code is ok. I do not know which extra '=' sign you mean.

Comment: Yea the code is ok. Sorry, I confused it with the `th:each` where the expression has `:` instead of `=`

Comment: But this answer is very close to my solution. While doing the th:with expression seems redundant to me. Basically this solution uses th:if and th:unless conditional statements.

Comment: I think it's not redundant. If you use only th:if and th:unless complex expression would be executed twice...

Comment: Yes, if you had read the question clearly, the OP has already tried the same code as you have provided in your solution as he also uses the same th:with expression block.

Comment: You should be using th:block instead of div when the only purpose is to introduce variable(s).

Answer (score 13):

In simpler case (when html tags is the same):

```
<h2 th:text="${potentially_complex_expression} ? 'Hello' : 'Something else'">/h2>
```

Comment: Do you know how to add translations for 'Hello' and 'Something else' in this expression?

Comment: @Laura You can use internationalization and load different language translations based on location from properties file. See https://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/internationalization/ , http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/12/springboot-thymeleaf-i18n-internationalization/

Comment: Quoting the question: "An important thing is that I use two different HTML tags: let's say `h2` and `span`."

Answer (score 11):

### Use `th:switch` as an `if-else`

```
<span th:switch="${isThisTrue}">
  <i th:case="true" class="fas fa-check green-text"></i>
  <i th:case="false" class="fas fa-times red-text"></i>
</span>
```

### Use `th:switch` as a `switch`

```
<span th:switch="${fruit}">
  <i th:case="Apple" class="fas fa-check red-text"></i>
  <i th:case="Orange" class="fas fa-times orange-text"></i>
  <i th:case="*" class="fas fa-times yellow-text"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is just using `not` to get the opposite negation:

```
<h2 th:if="${potentially_complex_expression}">Hello!</h2>
<span class="xxx" th:if="${not potentially_complex_expression}">Something else</span>
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless), it's the same thing as using `th:unless`. As other answers have explained:

> Also, `th:if` has an inverse attribute, `th:unless`, which we could have
>   used in the previous example **instead of using a not inside the OGNL
>   expression**

Using `not` also works, but IMHO it is more readable to use `th:unless` instead of negating the condition with `not`.

Comment: This still duplicates the expression, which is the exact thing the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div th:switch="true"> 
    <div th:case="${condition}=='1'">answer1...</div>
    <div th:case="${condition}=='2'">answer2...</div>
    <div th:case="*">answer3...</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for joining and contribution. At StackOverflow, you're encouraged to explain the answer, and not just provide a snippet.

Comment: Brilliant trick brother, thanks a ton. Worked like a charm!  This answer should go to the top, this is the true replacement for an if-else condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div th:switch="${user.role}"> 
<p th:case="'admin'">User is an administrator</p>
<p th:case="#{roles.manager}">User is a manager</p>
<p th:case="*">User is some other thing</p> 
</div>


<div th:with="condition=${potentially_complex_expression}" th:remove="tag">
<h2 th:if="${condition}">Hello!</h2>
<span th:unless="${condition}" class="xxx">Something else</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:100%">
<span th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 3)}">
<span th:if="${i == curpage}">
<a href="/listEmployee/${i}" class="btn btn-success custom-width" th:text="${i}"></a
</span>
<span th:unless="${i == curpage}">
<a href="/listEmployee/${i}" class="btn btn-danger custom-width" th:text="${i}"></a> 
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlGOB.png)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when I wanted to show a photo depending on the gender of the user:

```
<img th:src="${generou}=='Femenino' ? @{/images/user_mujer.jpg}: @{/images/user.jpg}" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3">
```

Answer (score 1):

If-then-else have 2 variant.

First:

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/{id}(id=${user.isAdmin()}?'admin':'user')}">
    <input type="submit" value="to Main"/>
</form>
```

Second:

```
<th:block th:if!="${branchMessages.isEmpty()}">
    ...
</th:block>
<th:block th:unless="${branchMessages.isEmpty()}">
    ...
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

If and unless sometimes fail to provide the expected result when using 2 separated blocks. If and else can also be achieved by using if statement in the first block for condition 1 (TRUE) and the second if statement is the second block for alternative choice when the first condition fails (FALSE).

Hoping that this will help.

```
<div th:with="condition=${potentially_complex_expression}" th:remove="tag">
   //True
   <h2 th:if="${if_condition}">Hello!</h2>

   //False
   <h2 th:if="${alternative_for_false}">Something else</h2>
</div>
```