# dealing with if condition in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and i've got a problem in performing if condition.The code i've written is

```
<tr th:if="${id &eq; 1 and mobNumber &eq; 1}" height="40" valign="top">
          //some code here
</tr>
```

The thing is this piece of code when written the web page keeps on loading.Can anyone tell me the right way to perform this action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do if-else in Thymeleaf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494078/how-to-do-if-else-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: If that provided the answer to your question, you should post it as a solution, @user2078883.

Answer (score 2):

Yo I got it just by replacing `&eq;` to `==` and it works excellently.I changed the code to

```
<tr th:if="${id==1 and mobNumber==1}" height="40" valign="top">
      //some code here
</tr>
```