# Concat String in Thymeleaf / Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I got the following line

```
<img data-language="de" th:onclick="'languageSwitch(this)'" src="/productfinder/images/blank.png" th:class="flag flag-de ${languageFilter.de} ? 'flag-active' : 'flag-disabled'" alt="Language Flag" />
```

Throws me:

> Could not parse as expression: "flag flag-de ${languageFilter.de} ? 'flag-active' : 'flag-disabled'"

Not quite sure what Im doing wrong here.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494078/how-to-do-if-else-in-thymeleaf

Comment: @RC. Thanks for the link. Tried that first solution, doesnt seem to work, no idea how to use that on my string ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for string literals and concatenate the literal to the class name returned by if-else, so

```
<img data-language="de" th:onclick="'languageSwitch(this)'" src="/productfinder/images/blank.png" th:class="'flag flag-de ' + ${languageFilter.de} ? 'flag-active' : 'flag-disabled'" alt="Language Flag" />
```

There is also available an attribute called `th:classappend`.

```
<img data-language="de" th:onclick="'languageSwitch(this)'" src="/productfinder/images/blank.png" th:class="flag flag-de" th:classappend="${languageFilter.de} ? 'flag-active' : 'flag-disabled'" alt="Language Flag" />
```

Documentation [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-and-prepending).