# Spring Boot display custom error message for different exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I am creating a `web application` using `Spring Boot`. In my `controller`, there can be situations when some `errors` occur. I need to **notify** my end users about these errors.

For example there might be an `error` while saving the data in the database. In this case I need to display a custom error message.

Also sometimes an `exception` might be thrown, a proper user friendly error message needs to be reported.

I read about using `ExceptionHandler` to do this. The problem is with this approach, I need to create different views (html files since I am using `Thymeleaf`) with the error message. So for each exception/error condition, I will need to create a separate HTML file with the hardcoded error message.

Is there anyway whereby a single error.html page can be used and the error message in that page customized depending on the exact error that has occured in the `controller`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Springs MVC` which means `Model View Controlling`. So on your page where you have the html to save data to your database, you are able to create html which is only shown if you need it. For example with `tymeleafs` `th:switch` or `th:if`. [find more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494078/how-to-do-if-else-in-thymeleaf)

In your business logic, you can create a simple `pojo` like `ExecptionMessage` where you set your exception message. When a real exception is thrown you can set the particular exception message to this object. In your `controller` you are now able to set the `ExecptionMessage` object to your view.

```
model.addAttribute("execptionMessage", new ExecptionMessage("My Custom message"));
```

This `model` is now available in the `view` and you are able to decide to show the message or not. So no need to create a new `html` for every error message. But you can think about creating a `thymeleaf template` to create the html just one time and include the `fragment` if needed. [find more...](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)

```
<div th:include="footer :: copy">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was useful!