# Thymeleaf switch on integer, case greater than

Tags: html, switch-statement, thymeleaf

This is probably an easy question but I can't seem to think of an answer to it.

I have this simple Thymeleaf code:

```
<ul data-th-switch="${someVar}">
    <li data-th-case="${gt 6}">someVar is greater than 6.</li>
    <li data-th-case="*">Default case.</li>
</ul>
```

I get an error on data-th-case="${gt 6}". Is there a way to do this in Thymeleaf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong indeed. [Details](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#comparators-and-equality).

A correct syntax one be `"${someVar} gt 6"` but of course, it will not work correctly, although the template will render. That is because `${someVar}` evaluates to 12 (for example) while `${someVar} gt 6` evaluates to `true`. These are not equal.

If you enable the ThyemeLeaf trace you will see how thymeleaf will interpret this:

```
o.t.s.expression.GreaterThanExpression   : Evaluating GREATER THAN expression: "${someVar} > 6". Left is "12", right is "6". Result is "true"
o.t.s.expression.EqualsExpression        : Evaluating EQUALS expression: "${someVar} == (${someVar} > 6)". Left is "12", right is "true". Result is "false"
```

Depending on the logic which you want to implement you may come to very different solutions - e.g. from putting a gadget in your model to implementing if-else logic. Check this question for some more [ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494078/how-to-do-if-else-in-thymeleaf).

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Lachezar Balev. I did indeed end up implementing some if-else blocks in order to solve this. I was actually migrating a JSP file to Thymeleaf and I got stuck on a <choose> tag. Surprised Thymeleaf doesn't have a similar functionality. In any case, you're absolutely right - I'm marking this as the answer.