# Thymeleaf show another image if not exists

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using the following image code that will show an image only if it exists.

```
<img th:if="${!ad.adPhotos.empty}" th:src="|/imageDisplay?id=${ad.adPhotos[0].id}|" alt="" class="img-respocive" />
```

I want to show this for the else caluse

```
<img height="150" width="150" src="img/NoPicAvailable.png" />
```

How would this be done with Thymeleaf?

Comment: Why not just `<img th:if="${ad.adPhotos.empty}" height="150" width="150" th:src="img/NoPicAvailable.png" />`?  Or even use `th:switch`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494078/how-to-do-if-else-in-thymeleaf

Comment: @bphilipnyc I ended using `th:if="${ad.adPhotos.empty}"`

Comment: another approach `th:src= "${ad.adPhotos.empty ? 'img/NoPicAvailable.png' : '/imageDisplay?id=' + ad.adPhotos[0].id}"`

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla I like your approach too

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it like this:

```
<img th:unless="${ad.adPhotos.empty}" th:src="|/imageDisplay?id=${ad.adPhotos[0].id}|" alt="" class="img-respocive" />
<img th:if="${ad.adPhotos.empty}"height="150" width="150" src="img/NoPicAvailable.png" />
```

As a sidenote, I think I would generate the src with thymeleaf url syntax, rather than string concatenation.

```
<img th:unless="${ad.adPhotos.empty}" th:src="@{/imageDisplay(id=${ad.adPhotos[0].id})}" alt="" class="img-respocive" />
```