# Thymeleaf list within list input

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, web-frontend

I have a data structure like this :-

```
WorkHistory{
    List<Jobs> jobs;
}
Jobs{
   List<String> workDoneSentences;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to collect all past jobs where a person has worked and the work that he hsa done there. So it is a list of list structure. I would like to know how can we handle this in UI for Thymeleaf/Spring mvc.

I am trying to create UI as shown in the images. There is a table to enter data. To enter workDoneSentence i would like to open another modal. And the list of sentences should be bound to correct job index.
[image]

[image]

Work Done opens the modal to take input the list of work done sentences.

The html code that I have for this as follows :-

```
<tbody>
    <tr id='addr_work0' th:each="workRow, rowStat : *{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData}">
        <td th:text="${rowStat.index + 1}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='work_name0'
            placeholder='Company Name'  class="form-control" th:field="*{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData[__${rowStat.index}__].companyName}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='work_city0'
            placeholder='Company city' class="form-control" th:field="*{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData[__${rowStat.index}__].city}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='work_title0'
            placeholder='Job Title' class="form-control" th:field="*{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData[__${rowStat.index}__].jobTitle}"/></td>
        <td><input name="is_current0" type="checkbox"
            value="" class="form-control" style="text-align: center;" th:field="*{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData[__${rowStat.index}__].currentJob}">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name='work_start0'
            placeholder='Start Date' class="form-control" th:field="*{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData[__${rowStat.index}__].startDate}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='work_end0'
            placeholder='End Date' class="form-control" th:field="*{workHistoryDetails.allWorkHistoryData[__${rowStat.index}__].endDate}"/></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="work_done0"
            name="work_done0">Work done</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr_work1'></tr>
</tbody>
```

I am not sure how I can link the workDone input. Please suggest.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of front end library are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried as follows and it works properly.

**Template:** Create unique "modal" for each job. (work-list.html)

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/work-list}" th:object="${workHistoryDetails}">
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>
      <button type="submit" name="addRow" th:text="'Add Row'">Add row</button>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr id='addr_work0' th:each="workRow, rowStat : *{jobs}">
    <td th:text="${rowStat.index + 1}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" 
                placeholder='Company Name'  class="form-control" th:field="*{jobs[__${rowStat.index}__].companyName}"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" 
                placeholder='Company city' class="form-control" th:field="*{jobs[__${rowStat.index}__].city}"/></td>


      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-target='#myModal'+${rowStat.index}" >Open modal</button></td>

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" th:id="'myModal'+${rowStat.index}">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>

         <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
           <input type="text"
                placeholder='Company Name'  class="form-control" th:field="*{jobs[__${rowStat.index}__].workDoneSentences[0]}"/>
           <input type="text" 
                placeholder='Company city' class="form-control" th:field="*{jobs[__${rowStat.index}__].workDoneSentences[1]}"/>
         </div>

         <!-- Modal footer -->
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-danger" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
@ModelAttribute("workHistoryDetails")
public WorkHistory populateWorkHistories() {
    return this.workHistory.getAllHistoryDetail();
}

@Autowired
WorkHistoryService workHistory;

@GetMapping("/work-list")
public String greeting(final WorkHistory workHistoryDetails) {
    return "work-list";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/work-list",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(final WorkHistory workHistoryDetails) {

   this.workHistory.setJobs(workHistoryDetails);
   return "work-list";
}

// for adding new row job to jobs list
@RequestMapping(value="/work-list", params={"addRow"})
public String addRow(final WorkHistory workHistoryDetails, Model model) {

    Jobs jobRow = new Jobs("","",new ArrayList<>());
    workHistoryDetails.getJobs().add(jobRow);
    model.addAttribute("workHistoryDetails", workHistoryDetails);
    return "work-list";
}
```

**Service:** Just for the sake of testing:

```
@Service
public class WorkHistoryService {

    static WorkHistory workHistoryDetails =new WorkHistory();
    static{
        List<String> workDones = new ArrayList<>();
        workDones.add("angular");
        workDones.add("description");
        List<String> workDones1 = new ArrayList<>();
        workDones1.add("java,c++");
        workDones1.add("description also");

        Jobs job1 = new Jobs("Twitter", "USA",workDones); 
        Jobs job2 = new Jobs("Microsoft", "USA",workDones1);
        List<Jobs> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
        jobList.add(job1);
        jobList.add(job2);
        workHistoryDetails.setJobs(jobList);
    }

    public WorkHistory getAllHistoryDetail(){

        return workHistoryDetails;
    }

    public void setJobs(WorkHistory workHistory){
        workHistoryDetails.getJobs().clear();
        List<Jobs> jobs = workHistory.getJobs();
        for (Jobs job : jobs) {
            workHistoryDetails.getJobs().add(job);
        }
    }
}
```

**Jobs domain:**

```
public class Jobs {
   private String companyName;
   private String city;
   private List<String> workDoneSentences;
    //default constructor important!   
    public Jobs() {
    super();
    }
   //setter getter
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for providing such an elaborate answer.But it is not working for me. I am getting Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "rowStat.index"  . It is not able to find rowStat within the modal body.

Comment: @jetty I tried it with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.10.RELEASE version and works well. If you want I will upload the project to Github.

Comment: That will be a great help. Will be able  to check the thymeleaf versions

Comment: What you have mentioned seems to be working with thymeleaf 3.09. But if put it in a tbody to generate workDone sentences generically. It still does not work

Comment: [Github Source](https://github.com/gurkan0791/spring-boot-work-history) @jetty I added the project maybe help you.

Comment: @jetty I added also "add row" button in the modal for dynamically adding work sentences row using jquery. You can check out Github link above.

Answer (score 5):

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="work_done0" name="work_done0"  th:href="Modal">Work done</a></td>
```

The Modal part should be configured per your own demand

Comment: How will the thymeleaf understand what is the Modal in  th:href="Modal" ?